# How to Fix Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Tags: vb.net-2010

I've been making a database for some payments and my code seems to have an error and I can't see where the problem is. I keep getting the "Syntax error in UPDATE statement" error in OleDbExecution was unhandled. Can someone help?

Here is my code:

```
Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection

Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDbCommand

Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\UBSOMSPayments.accdb")

If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
            cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE Payments SET Position='" & TextBox2.Text & "'," & "PaymentRecipient='" & TextBox3.Text & "'," & "PaymentFor='" & TextBox4.Text & "'," & "Amount='" & TextBox5.Text & "'," & "PayedAmount='" & TextBox6.Text & "'" & " WHERE AssignedOfficer = " & Val(TextBox1.Text)
            '1MsgBox(cmdUpdate.CommandText)
            cmdUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmdUpdate.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery() <--- Line where the error shows
            conn.Close()
            MsgBox("Record has been updated.")
        Else
            MsgBox("try again")
        End If
        cmdUpdate.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never use string concatenation to build SQL commands, but always a parameterized query to avoid SQL Injections.

**Try this:**

Change your query to something like this:

```
"UPDATE [Payments] SET [Position] = ?, [PaymentRecipient] = ?, [PaymentFor] = ?, " & _
  "[Amount] = ?, [PayedAmount] = ? & _
  " WHERE [AssignedOfficer] = ?"
```

and then add parameters:

```
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TextBox2.Text)
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", TextBox3.Text)   
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", TextBox4.Text)   
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", TextBox5.Text)
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", TextBox6.Text)
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", TextBox1.Text)
cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: is there a difference if I'm using access database? Anyway the same error still pops up. I have my table name and fields correctly spelled here if you might say that's the reason.

Comment: @Erick I have updated my answer. Try to escape the columns with the updated query and let me know if that works.